# Скрипт загрузки .rar, .zip файлов на сервер

Tags: php

Пишу пхп скрипт загрузки файлов на сервер. Все работает, вот только хочу сделать, что бы загружало только .rar, .zip файлы. Подскажите, как это сделать.

```
if($_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"] ==application/x-tar )
   {
     echo ("токо rar файлы");
     exit;
   }
```

Comment: Проверяйте лучше расширение в имени пришедшего файла.  
Например: если у пользователя не установлен обработчик rar архивов, то Вам не придет его mime. Если не ошибусь придет application/octet-stream.

Comment: @ReinRaus, согласен, но лучше сделать дополнительную проверку.

Comment: разве? обработчик тут не причем, на сервере вообщето в вебсервере все обработчики задаются и серверу пофиг что у тебя на компе к чему привязано...

Comment: А можете кому не сложно подкорректировать код.

Comment: @thunder, чтобы не быть голословным проводил эксперимент и в сокет записывал следующие данные в HTTP запросе:  

    --aSaSaSaS1221
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="backdoor.php"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    
    text
    --aSaSaSaS1221--

Comment: Сервер просто делает `var_dump($_FILES)`:  

    array(1) {
        ["file1"]=>
        array(5) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(12) "backdoor.php"
            ["type"]=>
            string(10) "image/jpeg"
            ["tmp_name"]=>
            string(18) "Z:\tmp\php9C53.tmp"
            ["error"]=>
            int(0)
            ["size"]=>
            int(5)
        }
    }
Это означает, что если у пользователя будет отсутствовать программа соответствующая, то MIME вообще не будет установлен в заголовке запроса, и на сервере нет никаких обработчиков- MIME задает браузер.

Comment: Да, вы правы, не задавался этим вопросом =) Спасибо

Вы, наверное, можете спросить: "А зачем надо проверять и расширение, и MIME-type?". Тут очень важно понимать, что это далеко не одно и то же. Если злоумышленник попытается отправить PHP-файл через браузер, то и одной проверки MIME-type хватит, чтобы его попытка провалилась. А вот если он напишет какой-нибудь скрипт, который будет формировать запрос и отсылать вредосный файл, то этого не хватит.

Comment: Почему? А потому, что MIME-type задаётся клиентом, а не сервером! И фактически, злоумышленник может поставить любой MIME-type (и картинки тоже), но при этом отсылать PHP-скрипт. И вот именно такую хитрую попытку мы и ломаем, проверяя на расширение файла.

Comment: @thunder если бы я делал что-то подобное, то проверял бы только расширение :-) этого достаточно для защиты от  загрузки шелла.  
Если нужна проверка на валидность, что это действительно архив или действительно картинка, то нужно задействовать zlib и gdlib соответственно, а проверка MIME мне кажется является неправильным программированием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот пример обработки загруженных файлов.

```
  $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4", ".html", ".htm");
  foreach ($blacklist as $item)
    if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['somename']['name'])) exit;
  $type = $_FILES['somename']['type'];
  $size = $_FILES['somename']['size'];
  if (($type != "image/jpg") && ($type != "image/jpeg")) exit;
  if ($size > 102400) exit;
  $uploadfile = "images/".$_FILES['somename']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['somename']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

в вашем случае type может быть application/rar и application/zip
т.е. можно сделать так:

```
$allowed_exts = array("rar", "zip");
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES['somename']['name']);
$allowed_types = array("application/rar","application/zip");
if (in_array($_FILES["uploadfile"]["type"], $allowed_types) && in_array($file_info['extension'], $allowed_exts) ) {
//работаем с файлами,
} else {
 echo "Ошибка! Тип {$_FILES['uploadfile']['type']} запрещен либо файл имеет неверное расширение ({$file_info['extension']}).";
}
```

Comment: @ReinRaus прав, поправил скрипт, чтобы еще и расширение проверялось :)